# Most suitable blog for private statuses & photos

Tags: blog, photos, photo-sharing

Since the birth of my daughter I have been looking for the most optimum way of sharing events and photos in her life with my family. But I am struggling to finding a blog tool that fulfils all my requirements.

Currently I am using a mixture of email, Dropbox, Picasa and Facebook, plus the odd post on Twitter, Flickr and Google+. This is however a mess for family to keep up with, and I would like a chronological order of all posts about her, like a baby photo album of old.

My requirements are:

- All or most posts & photos are private not public
- Can upload a lot of photos
- Can post the odd status (eg first tooth, steps, weight etc)
- Will be around for quite a while.

---

My deductions so far:

Google+ has nice features. The Circles is a great way of restricting access. The Picasa integration for photos is excellent. However Google plus is a non starter as you [cannot create an account for a minor](https://plus.google.com/114311896476820866022/posts/QkKTxAbKGdq), I don't think you can create multiple accounts, and I do not want to mix my own unrelated posts with hers.

Facebook is an alternative. The new timeline does browse nicely. But probably not allowed to create an account for 0 year old...

Picasa is a great online photo album for bulk private photos. But photos & videos only.
I used to run my own [Coppermine](http://coppermine-gallery.net/), but prefer a hosted service. Again photos only.
Same for Dropbox.

A private Blogger blog is possibly a solution. Not sure how it does it with loads of photos per post. But will google kill it soon and merge it with google+?

The problem with Google+ & Facebook etc is to convince my relatives to create accounts. My mum is very anti FB etc... Sending a direct private link is usually the easier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a [Posterous](http://posterous.com) private space?

From http://www.forbes.com/sites/tomiogeron/2011/09/12/posterous-is-now-spaces-a-photo-focused-app-for-private-sharing/ :

> The feature that will make Posterous Spaces easy to connect with
>   non-technical friends or family members is email. When a Posterous
>   user shares photos with family members who are not registered on
>   Posterous, those family members will still receive the photos via
>   email [...] Unlike photo apps such as the popular Instagram app,
>   with Posterous you can post multiple photos in one post, and you can
>   create private groups.

Comment: Having a look at Posterous now. Seems good.